# Paper.js canvas change function triggered by button

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, paperjs

I am trying to update my canvas which uses paper.js via a button click. Why is the button not aware of my changePos() function?

```
 <div class="myCanvas">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
  </div>

  <button id="some_button" onClick='changePos();'>Change Position</button>
```

In the following scripts the first script is paper.js and the second script initializes text "hey" on my canvas. This is where the changePos() function is located that in my mind the button should be calling when it is clicked.

```
<script src="/paperjs/paper.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script  type="text/paperscript" canvas="canvas">

var text = new PointText({
      point: view.center,
      justification: 'center',
      fontSize: 20,
      fillColor: 'black'

    });

function init() {
  text.position = view.center;
      text.content = "hey"; 
}

function changePos() {
  text.content = "200";
}

init();
</script>
```

Comment: i'm facing the same probleme , it apears that the paperscript script is beyond the scope of simple html component such as buttons .

Comment: thanks for the response @FrozenFlame I'm basically just trying to move text across a box and hide it so other text can appear over it. I'm thinking of using plain ol' javascript instead. Did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

You will probably find my answer regarding [Paper.js Interoperability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24439046/paper-js-interoperability) usefull.

In order to be able to access `changePos()` from the outside, you need to export it through globally defined object, e.g. globals, or exports, and then access it there in the JavaScript.