# Paper.js Interoperability

Tags: javascript, html, interop, paperjs

I would like to call paper.js functions from HTML buttons in my page but I believe the paper.js functions exist in their own scope. The paper.js docs mention interoperability which sounds like the right direct by then take me to a page that says "coming soon":

http://paperjs.org/tutorials/getting-started/paperscript-interoperability/

Does anyone know how I can call a function created within a paper.js script from my HTML page?

Answer (score 5):

Apologies for that missing tutorial. I shall really invest some time into writing it finally.

I've answered this question on the mailing list last year: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/paperjs/C6F0XFlplqM/_67AMqCR_nAJ

> Scoped PaperScript run inside the global scope, and have access to all elements of the global scope. The normal JavaScripts running in the global scope (= window) will not see these PaperScopes, and won't have access to their variables.
>
> There is a simple solution to exchange information between the two: Simply declare a global structure that you use to exchange tings back and forth, e.g.

```
window.globals = {
    someValue: 10,
    someFunction: function() { alert(globals.someValue); }
};
```

> In your PaperScript, you can then access this simply through 'globals', since it's in the window scope:

```
globals.someValue = 20;
globals.someFunction();
```

And in the same way, you can use this structure from normal JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for this comment but it's still a bit vague compared to the rest of the documentation. Any progress on the Interoperability page?

Comment: thanks, this is working but I how can I disable the behavior of paperscript, I want to drive all my paper script functionality through jquery click events

Answer (score 3):

I just wanted to add some clarification for anyone who runs into this.

For PaperScript-to-JavaScript interoperability, do the following...

In HTML file:

```
<button type="button" id="btn">Click Me!</button>
```

In JavaScript file:

```
$(document).ready(init);

function init(jQuery) {
  $("#btn").click(window.globals.paperClicked);
}

// PaperScript Interop
window.globals = {
  paperClicked: function() {}
}
```

In PaperScript file:

```
// JavaScript Interop
globals.paperClicked = internalClicked;

function internalClicked() {
  alert('clicked!');
}
```

Comment: thanks, this is working but I how can I disable the behavior of paperscript, I want to drive all my paper script functionality through jquery click events.