# paperjs: How to split my code up into multiple files?

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I've been messing around with paperjs for a while and have written a 1500+ lines of code single file that I'd really love to split up into multiple files to make it more readable. 
Initially I thought i could just make a `library.js` file that I'd put in the `public/scripts` directory and load into my page using `<script src="/scripts/library.js"></script>`. However, calling any function that is retained in `library.js` would then yield an error such as:

> ReferenceError: Path is not defined

So how would i store functions in- and use them from external files the right way?

Comment: Do you load _paperjs_ before your library ?

Comment: I tried both before and after actually, it yields the same errors.

Comment: How is your library code structured ?

Comment: As a trial I only added a single function to it so far. So my `library.js` simply contains `function fooBar() { //dosomething }` if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You got that error because you miss to [set](http://paperjs.org/tutorials/getting-started/working-with-paper-js/#script-configuration) your  tag type to `"text/paperscript"`, and not `"text/javascript"` like you use for loading *paperjs*.

Try this way:

```
<!-- Load the Paper.js library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="paper-full.min.js"></script>
<!-- Load external PaperScript and associate it with myCanvas -->
<script type="text/paperscript" src="library.js" canvas="myCanvas"></script>

<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" resize></canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: Would this allow me to segment my code into different files and load them ALL into the same canvas? I get the feeling that if I want to load multiple scripts this way and assign them all to `canvas="myCanvas"`, I'll just end up overwriting instead of expanding. Would that assessment be correct?

Comment: Ok that's strange then because it definitely still gives me errors.

Comment: So a big difference is the type of error though. Previously it was 'ReferenceError: Path is not defined" whereas now it's "ReferenceError: fooBar is not defined".

Comment: I'm agree with you that it is not very intuitive, but you need to make your function global with something like `window.fooBar = fooBar;` and then call your function with `window.fooBar()`, thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32053489/5156280). There is also a [`PaperScope()`](http://paperjs.org/reference/paperscope/) you could investigate.